# Angular ngoninit didn't returns the updated mongodb collections

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, nginx

ngoninit is not giving the latest updated collection from mongodb.But when i refresh the browser, then i got the updated data from the database but if i change the route's  then it is not working .I have a nodejs code and mongodb as a supporting database running at nginx server. I have a front end running at localhost:4200 i.e its angular js project.

Let's say i have one route (/admin/create/) for inserting a data and one route to get the data (/admin/getall). Now when i insert the data and navigate to getall route....i got nothing but when i refresh the page with manual browser refresh, then i get the data.

I don't know whether the issue is with mongodb, nginx, angular. Or nodejs

EDIT: here is the code screenshot of the api call:

this the service call for the news data in the component ts file
**code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { NewsService } from "../../../service/news.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-admin-all-news",
  templateUrl: "./admin-all-news.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./admin-all-news.component.css"]
})
export class AdminAllNewsComponent implements OnInit {
  allNews = [];
  constructor(private newsService: NewsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newsService.getNews().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.allNews.push(res.data.news);
    });
  }
}
```

and here is the service file from which backend call is being send
**code:**

```
       /*get All Content  here*/
  getNews() {
    return this.https.get(environment.foxtailURL + "api/admin/news");
  }
```

The url for the backend is hosted at ip address:xxx.xx.xxx.xxx running with nginx.

the route for the current component is something like localhost:4200/route-path;
but whenever i visit this route i get the old data values until or unless i refresh the web browser page manually.

This is working fine if i have angular and nodejs,backend both running at local server but whenever i connect my local angular with the hosted server ip, then this problem occurs. I have got 2-3 angular projects,this is the problem with all of them.

Comment: Since you mentioned the data comes when you refresh the browser, the issue is most probably with Angular. Please provide some code so we can help you better.

Comment: @nash11 check out the image links of the component.ts file and service file

Comment: First of all I would recommend that you do not share code snippets as images but instead use the option of posting your, in this case two, code snippets directly alongside the problem description. This does not only improve readability, but also makes searching and debugging possible bugs in the provided code (snippets) easier for the people who look at this post and want to help you.

Comment: Second, your code snippet (in form of an image) that shows the method of your service file, is another method than the one that is called in your `component.ts` file. Please provide the correct code by pasting your code snippets into the text field and use the formatting functionality to format your code properly!

Comment: @Bajro  code snippet uploaded

Comment: Good. Coming back to your original question: Since the code looks right, I would assume that the problem is with your backend or nginx. Try to send a `GET` request to the same resource as stated in the `getNews()` method (i.e. `api/admin/news`) and test if you get any data.

Comment: @Bajro i always get the news if i hit the same api but the thing is i didnot get the updated collection,(for example: let say there are 10 entries in my collection and if i insert one more entry, then doesn't matter how many time i visit my component route it will not give me the updated collection, until or unless i will make a manual browser refresh  but if i hit the same back end Api with the postman,then i always get the updated collection.